# When I do overflow-x hidden on li in primefaces I get a strange artifact, what is it and why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf, primefaces

How can I make long items stop wrapping?

[image: I don't want items to wrap.]

I added the following css:

```
li.ui-selectlistbox-item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Which gave me the following result:

[image: I don't want items to wrap.]

Then I tried:

```
li.ui-selectlistbox-item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Which gave me the following result:

[image: I don't want items to wrap.]

Then I tried:

```
li.ui-selectlistbox-item {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Which gave me the following result:

[image: How do I get rid of those grey boxes?]

The last version of the css gives me essentially what I want but it introduces grey boxes at the end of each value row.  What are these boxes?, where do they come from? why are they there? how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Could you give a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jaxon I cannot because doing pure, simple html5 ul doesn't exhibit the issue.  Something to do with how primefaces constructs html or the css files included by primefaces causes the issue, I'm posting the question because I have been unable to recreate the issue outside of primefaces and unable to get the desired result within primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey boxes are tiny scrollbars within each li.
Try to do it with `overflow: hidden`

```
li.ui-selectlistbox-item {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcel that is hilarious, a vertical scroll bar.  I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.  I never would have guessed that.

Comment: @RobertoMurphy I had my fair share of such things happening myself, it's all about clicking on just the right spot :)